# How to share wifi on mac using 2 wifi adapters, built in and usb

Tags: macos, wifi, adapter, sharing

Its not specifically programming, however I think programmers are more likely to be able to help me on this one.

I'm trying to share my wifi from my usb wifi adapter through my mac and out of my mac built in wifi and when I share the wifi this way is works for about 3 seconds and then starts searching for a network and stops broadcasting wifi.

So this happens:

[image: Wifi adapter connected to internet]

Then it broadcasts wifi

[image: broadcasting wifi for 3 seconds]

Then is stops broadcasting 3 seconds later and starts searching for a new network

[image: Stops broadcasting 3 seconds later]

Please can someone help me resolve this and no I cant use ethernet for this and yes it is 2 adapters not one.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem, turns out this method is very temperamental for some strange and unexplainable reason.

This method works and you can broadcast any wifi you are connected to using 2 wifi adapters one being the built in wifi card on mac and the other being a usb wifi adapter, mine is a 150Mbps wireless TP-Link nano usb adapter.

To solve my problem, and others that I ran into with no apparent 'fix', is to make sure you are broadcasting through channel 11 as for some reason this one just works and also if it isn't working just try to restart your mac till it works, seriously I'm not joking. I don't know how or why but restarting your mac repeatedly just fixes whatever unsolvable problem you may have. And I will emphasise this again just restart, and yes, until your mac wifi sharing works.